# How to make Vim suggest object's public members?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, vim-plugin, autosuggest

How can you configure Vim in such a way that, if you are using an object `foo`, as soon as you type `foo.` or `foo->` it suggests you the public members (methods/attributes) that that object's interface provides so you can see what you can do and/or auto-complete?

I'm using [YCM](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe), but it adds a lot of clutter when I do what I've described. It not only suggests public members but also any known name that matches what I'm typing (even if the object doesn't provide that). I'm mainly interested in C++ and Python.

Comment: There are several plugins that can do that; haven't you found any? It depends a lot on the programming language (C++ / Java / Python / ...)

Comment: I'm using [YCM](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe), but it adds a lot of clutter when I do what I've described. It not only suggests public members but also any known name that matches what I'm typing (even if the object doesn't provide that). I'm mainly interested in C++ and Python.

Comment: I've edited your comment into the question, as I think that's really crucial information. I was also thinking about YCM, as it's one of the most prominent plugins that provide this completion feature.

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked what you describe with vim and YCM plugin and I get exactly what you want, in C++ and Python. Could you check/try the following:

- Do you have the latest version of YCM?
- Do you have a .ycm_extra_conf.py for your C++ project (or a global default one)
- In some rare cases the YCM seems not to trigger the semantic completion (at least on my machine) but the usual (buffer/tag/...) completion. Try CTRL + space in that case to get semantic completion.